# app crashing when uiimage created with +imageNamed: is released in dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why does my app crash when i try to release the image I created with +imageNamed: inside dealloc.  My code is as follows:

MyClass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyClass{
    UIImage *_thumbImage;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *thumbImage;
@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize thumbImage = _thumbImage;
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.thumbImage = [UIImage imagedNamed:@"myImage.png""];
}
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    self.thumbImage = nil;
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [_thumbImage release]; //if i leave this here, the app crashes.  should i release my property?
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dealloc method, you need to move `[super dealloc]` to the bottom.  You're trying to access your object's instance variable after it's been dealloced.

Comment: thx it worked.  so should [super dealloc] always be called at the end of the dealloc method?  i thought super dealloc just removes the instance variables in the parent class, why would it affect the retain count of ivars in my subclass?

Comment: [super dealloc] doesn't change the retain count of your instance variables.  It tells the OS that your object's memory can be freed.  So when you try to access the instance variable after that, you're referencing memory that you no longer own.

Comment: ... so yes.  Always call [super dealloc] last.

Answer (score 0):

> [UIImage imagedNamed:@"myImage.png""];

is autoreleased. It is also memory managed for you. If you need to release it immediately then alloc/init a UIImage or create UIImageView.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyClass{
}
@end


#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(0,0,100,200)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imagedNamed:@"myImage.png""];
    [self.view addSubView:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
-(void)viewDidUnload{
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: The setter will retain it automatically.

Comment: @cduhn answer fixes the problem, but if you don't need to keep the image around, then I'd do it my way.

Comment: Removing David's thumbImage property isn't necessary.  You're assuming he wants to assign it to a UIImageView and display it.  He may want to save a reference to it for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release your stuff first, then call `[super dealloc]`. `[super dealloc]` will release the classes memory and accessing an ivar afterwards will result in an segfault.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to review apples memory management guide here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Particularly the section stating:

**You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.**

Since you are not using one of these functions you do not have ownership of the object and therefore can not release it.

Comment: That is correct, but he's assigning the image to a retaining property => it should be released.